# Adjusting width of column to content in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want the columns of my table to adjust its width to the biggest element.
Like doubleclicking an excel-column...

I've tried lots of attributes and solutions of other questions but nothing really did what i wanted.

Here are my settings for the dataTable which is nested in a p:scollPanel:

```
<p:dataTable scrollable="true" scrollWidth="auto" scrollHeight="390"
             tableStyle="width: auto; white-space: nowrap; font-size: smaller"
             id=carTable" var="vehicles"
             value="#{dgBean.vehicles}">
```

Using:

- primefaces 6.0
- jsf 2.2.1

UPDATE:

I don't know why, but it seems like table-layout: auto is not used AND two divs are generated. 1 for the Header of my table and the other for the body of my table.
That's why the first layout I've posted shows up and the header and body fit nicely on their own but the header doesn't fit the body.

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget-header ui-datatable-scrollable-header" style="width: 1199px;">
    <div class="ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box" style="margin-right: 15px;">
        <table role="grid">
            <thead id="j_idt5:j_idt14:carTable_head">...</thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-datatable-scrollable-body" tabindex="-1" style="height: 390px; margin-right: 0px; width: 1199px;">
    <table role="grid">
        <thead class="ui-datatable-scrollable-theadclone" style="height: 0px;">...</thead>
        <tbody id="j_idt5:j_idt14:carTable_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content" tabindex="0">...</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So it seems like 2 tables are generated. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this using pf?

UPDATE from comment

Applying

```
.ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box table, .ui-datatable-scrollable-footer-box table, .ui-datatable-scrollable-body table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

to the [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml)
produces (deleted my former images as reputation is not high enough for more than 2):

[Showcase with edited css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pGCw.png)

Comment: does it work if you remove the custom css?

Comment: @Kukeltje i guess you mean the primefaces theme? no it doesn't change a thing

Comment: no the tableStyle stuff and if it still does not work, also check the issuelist and try a newer version (try, just for this issue)

Comment: i've added a pic without the tableStyle element. newer pf version? i'll try later, busy now :-)

Comment: i've tried the newer version and running 6.0 now. didn't change a thing. i couldn't find an issue with a similar case either :-( bypassed it by setting scrollWidth to 250% to enlarge all columns, but still this isnt what i want

Comment: Two table are needed for the scrolling. You can unfortunately still not do this natively in one html table.

Comment: ok. seems to me like scrollable fixes the table layout again as i have found it in <table> implemented by .ui-datatable-scrollable and .ui-datatable (parent elements have layout set to auto). if i untick them both it looks like before... body is fine but the headers is having other widths :-(

Comment: it is quite ok as it is now... but if i put a footer using a facet under the table it adopts the 250% width and the scrollbar for that table is only visibly if you scroll to the end... -.-

Comment: See my comment on the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Are you **sure** the table-layout: auto is applied to your header and footer table? Check if the generated html is in one way or another different then the single scrollable vertical datatable in the showcase and try see if the css needs some adatption

Answer (score 16):

> [I want the columns of my table to adjust its width to the biggest element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852704/adjusting-width-of-column-to-content-in-pdatatable)

PrimeFaces DataTable default style uses `table-layout: fixed;`. So **if only that**, replace your `tableStyle` content with `table-layout: auto;` to make usage of the automatic table layout algorithm as stated on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp):

> The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells

From everthing you wrote (including comments) until now, I assume you want a **vertically and horizontally scrollable** *DataTable* that **automatically sizes its columns** to its content.

**I claim this is not possible** with the built in functionalities of PrimeFaces *DataTable*, because as you allready noted, if you make the *DataTable* scrollable, the rendered output differs in that there are different tables for the header, body and footer (to make header and footer sticky).

> [I don't get it why its not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852704/adjusting-width-of-column-to-content-in-pdatatable/38855668?noredirect=1#comment65140412_38855668)

Column sizes calculated with the automatic table layout algorithm with `table-layout: auto;` will differ for all three tables (except they incidentally have the same broadest unbreakable content, like header and footer in [ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml)). The difference in size gets relativated if the table gets broader (because additional space is equaly distributed to the columns), so it might look like everthing is OK as [Kukeltje commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852704/adjusting-width-of-column-to-content-in-pdatatable/38855668?noredirect=1#comment65124911_38855668). But if you shrink the width of the table, differences get visible.

```
             |  broadest content   | stretched by 1000
--------------------------------------------------------
             | column 1 | column 2 | column 1 | column 2
--------------------------------------------------------
header table | 2        | 3        | 502      | 503
body table   | 4        | 6        | 504      | 506
footer table | 2        | 3        | 502      | 503
```

As you maybe have noticed, the rendered body table also contains the header content but hidden. So assumed the header content would be broader than the body content, everything would be fine at least for the header and body table.

```
                   |  broadest content
========================================
                   | column 1 | column 2
========================================
header table       | 5        | 7
----------------------------------------
hidden header part | 5        | 7
body part          | 4        | 6
________________________________________
body table         | 5        | 7
----------------------------------------
footer table       | 2        | 3
```

**The easiest workaround** is to disable scrollability and enable pagination. With this, you have a more or less controllable height of the *DataTable* (with *rows* attribute) while preserving the remaining requirements.

> [From my point of view the paginator looks like it is just replacing the vertical scrolling.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852704/adjusting-width-of-column-to-content-in-pdatatable/38855668?noredirect=1#comment65140412_38855668)

More or less (therefore the easiest workaround). Most important thing is that only one table is renderd and therefore header, body and footer content is used to calculate the column widths:

```
            |  broadest content
---------------------------------
            | column 1 | column 2
---------------------------------
header part | 2        | 3
body part   | 4        | 6
footer part | 2        | 3
_________________________________
full table  | 4        | 6
```

> [How does that aid my horizontal problem?](http://From%20my%20point%20of%20view%20the%20paginator%20looks%20like%20it%20is%20just%20replacing%20the%20vertical%20scrolling.)

With `table-layout: auto;` you get horizontal scrolling within the paginator viewport out of the box.

**Another approach** is to disable scrollability and wrap the *DataTable* with a *ScrollPanel*. This has some disadvantages in that the header is scrollable too and there are issues with resizing you have to handle, so I would not recommend it.

**Best solution** will be a customized renderer (note the hidden header content in the rendered body table if scrollability is enabled and extend vice verca) and/or customized JS/CSS for your *DataTable*, but thats out of scope of your question.

**Easiest solution** would be to not insist on automatic column sizing according to table content and take DataTable with scrolling capabilities as is.

Comment: I've tried that one too ofc ... without success. As meantioned I HAVE read the others questions here. I guess that the first attribute in my settings means my dataTable is supposed to be scrollable ( :-P ). Just columns in the table no columnGroups.

Comment: @cluecke You said, you have read other questions here, but not which ones. Sorry, i am not a psychic. So beside your requirement to adjust columns width to the content, your DataTable should be scrollable?

Comment: @cluecke: if you apply what is proposed above, where does the `table-layout: auto` end up? Since if I apply it explicitly to each table in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml) (header, body and footer) it works for me. `.ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box table, 
.ui-datatable-scrollable-footer-box table, 
.ui-datatable-scrollable-body table{
  table-layout: auto;
}`

Comment: @Kukeltje it always ends when the <table>-Element starts where .ui-datatable-scrollable table and .ui-datatable table kick in with the layout: fixed. If i change those 2 to auto it's as meantioned before. :-( i'm not sure if i am applying your solution the right way. could you explain it (and make it a seperated answer) please? :-)

Comment: Just apply the css from my comment as is. When I apply that to the showcase, it works. Then it is not like you mentioned before. And there was a question in ky commemt above

Comment: @Kukeltje if i apply this to the showcase the header width doesn't fit the width of its body as it does with my table. I'll link the outcome in my question. and yes it hase to be scrollable as i have many columns

Comment: applying it to the live showcase does not work unless you use something like 'stylish' (which I did). You can also run the showcase locally, sorry if this was not clear

Comment: locally same outcome

Comment: @irieill it should be horizonally scrollable too :-) just as the showcase is and i don't get it why its not working :-( from my point of view the paginator looks like it is just replacing the vertical scrolling. How does that aid my horizontal problem?

Comment: @irieill ty for all your hard work, i'll see what the paginator does later. atm i have my scrollable datatable nested in a panel. the width of the datatable is set to 240% (to make the fixed columns broad enough) and the scrollWidth to 100% to make it fit the panel :-( looks ok atm but if your paginator works i gonna use that ofc :-)

Comment: Another workaround is to enable resizableColumns: this mean that the user has to resize them manually but this is better than having truncated text that you cannot read in any way.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue header and table content width was different, i created below css and worked like a charm for me, don't have to remove anything like filters or scrollbars

```
.ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box table th, .ui-datatable-scrollable-footer-box table th, .ui-datatable-scrollable-body table td{
   width: 20% !important;
}
```